# Blue screen after booting up PC

Tags: wireless-networking, boot, drivers, windows-8.1

I have been getting a blue screen of dead on my win8.1 machine immediately after powering it up with error message WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR. and I am not sure what is causing it. 
After some googling I followed a procedure to get a report from windows debugger but cannot make sense of it. It started happening after I put an Asus PCE AC68U nic, however I am not sure if this is the cause and what to do. Could anyone please have a look at the report and advise please.

I have an Intel i7 4770k overclocked to 4.8 GHz using Asus AI-Suite3, Asus Z87 Pro Motherboard, 16 GB of Ram, Corsair H100i watercooling system. GTX660 GPU, 750W PSU
CPU temp never exceeds 30 Celsius

Many Thanks.

```
*******************************ERROR REPORT********************

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.17237 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Bitmap Dump File: Only kernel address space is available


************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*C:\Windows\symbol_cache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: SRV*C:\Windows\symbol_cache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 8 Kernel Version 9600 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Built by: 9600.17085.amd64fre.winblue_gdr.140330-1035
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`36e7a000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`371442d0
Debug session time: Wed Aug 13 20:06:27.484 2014 (UTC + 8:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 2:00:21.135
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
.............................................................
Loading User Symbols

Loading unloaded module list
................
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 9F, {3, ffffe001bb366450, ffffd001a866a930, ffffe001c28ddb10}

Probably caused by : pci.sys

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

4: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffe001bb366450, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: ffffd001a866a930, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffe001c28ddb10, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  53089439

MODULE_NAME: pci

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff800c756b000 pci

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17237 (debuggers(dbg).140716-0327) amd64fre

DPC_STACK_BASE:  FFFFD001A8671FB0

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd001`a866a8f8 fffff801`37076c1e : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000003 ffffe001`bb366450 ffffd001`a866a930 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffd001`a866a900 fffff801`37076b3e : ffffe001`c214b680 fffff801`36e0f39a ffffe001`c214b6c0 ffffe001`c214b6f8 : nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck+0xde
ffffd001`a866a960 fffff801`36ed3810 : 00000000`00000000 ffffd001`00000001 ffffd001`acf27b70 ffffd001`00000002 : nt!PopIrpWatchdog+0x32
ffffd001`a866a9b0 fffff801`36fd1aea : ffffd001`a8640180 ffffd001`a8640180 ffffd001`a864c3c0 ffffe001`c1233080 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x4f0
ffffd001`a866ac60 00000000`00000000 : ffffd001`a866b000 ffffd001`a8665000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.3.9600.17031

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_athw8x_IMAGE_pci.sys

BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_athw8x_IMAGE_pci.sys

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_power_down_athw8x_image_pci.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {cfa68862-d7f0-2458-a20b-197724c77461}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: First step; restore your CPU to the default clock speeds; we have to rule stuff out and a 4.8ghz overclock is pretty severe (good) but could be the cause; also tell us what drivers are loaded at the time of the BSOD with something like BlueScreenViewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`athw8x.sys` = Atheros WIFI driver. Download the latest driver from here:

https://www.atheros.cz/atheros-wireless-drivers.html

To Fix the [0x124 bugcheck (WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), disable the Overclocking and go back to the default clock speed.